# If you use with() in a query in Laravel how do you select specific columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So if you have:

```
Book::with('author:id,name')->get()
```

I know it's possible to define specific columns in the association. 
How can you access the author relation in the select function with other fields from the main table?

```
Book::select('title','author.name')->with('author')->get();
```

Comment: Book::with('author:id,name')->get - where did you take that from?

Comment: Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify columns to fetch for relation, you need to execute the **select()** method on the query builder that will be fetching data from related table. The following code does that:

```
Book::with('author' => function($builder) {
  $builder->select('name');
})->select('someFieldFromBookModel', 'author_id')-get();
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I select 1 column from the book table at the same time?

Comment: I just updated the answer. You must fetch the foreign key as well, otherwise Eloquent won't be able to match authors against books.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". And run getSql() instead of get() and let me know what it returns.